# Could not format the Namenode in hadoop 2.6?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have installed the hadoop 2.6 on ubuntu 14.04.I just followed [this blog](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php).

While I am trying to format the namenode, I am hitting with below error:

> hduser@data1:~$ hadoop namenode -format 
>   DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 276: /home/hduser/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you please share the configurations. Also share the value of JAVA_HOME

Comment: fixed the problem.. I have just added the line export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME in the bashrc file .Now its working fine .Also i was faced some problem while the formatting the namenode ..that problem was fixed by after deleting the namenode and datanode folder .And again formatted the namenode .Thanks! –

Answer (score 0):

> /home/hduser/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory

This error occurs because the JAVA_HOME you have provided does not have java.

Just add this line in `hadoop-env.sh` and `/home/hduser/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments .Already i have provided the java path in hadoop-env.sh file..But still i am getting the error ..Any idea about the following path /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 276: /home/hduser/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: Post the contents of `hadoop-env.sh` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already set the $JAVA_HOME but you did it wrong (just a guess):

/home/hduser/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

It would be :

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

You probably have added ~ before the path when you exported that JAVA_HOME and this added the home directory `/home/hduser`.

To check this out, type `java -version` and see if java is working. And type `echo $JAVA_HOME` and check the path manually.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ..java path was correct ..that is  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java in the bashrc file ..                                                          I have just added the line export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME in the bashrc file .Now its working fine .Also i was faced some problem while  the formatting the namenode ..that problem was fixed by  after deleting the namenode and datanode folder .And again formatted the namenode .Thanks!

Comment: java path is not the issue .please see my above comments Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. The entry we made was for amd64. it is really i386 computers. Please verify the path and that should fix the issue.